# Visual Studio 2010 - Source code disappeared from project folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I created a Win32 Console project (C++) using Visual Studio 2010 by pasting multiple files into the solution explorer window (This project was created as an empty project).  But when I go to the file directory of my project (to zip up the source files) they are not visible.  Where did my files go?  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking in the properties window when you have the file selected - it should give you the path to it

Answer (score 2):

It's possible it created a reference to the original path you copied them from.  You might need to copy them to the correct folder in windows explorer (outside Visual Studio), and then right-click to add an existing item to the project.